# Calling a parametrized method from LibraryCollection class to main Class

Tags: java

I am working on library management system project. Below is my LibraryCollection class. I would like to call my findMaterials() and checkOutMaterial() methods in the main class.

I have been trying to call as in below method but I don't get any value in the console.

```
public static LibraryCollection librarycollectObj1 = new LibraryCollection(10); 
String search = null; 
librarycollectObj1.findMaterial(search);
```

Thanks;

//LibraryCollection Class
    public class LibraryCollection 
    {
        private int collectionMaxSize; 
        private Material[] libraryCollection;

```
    public LibraryCollection(int theMaxSize)
    {
        collectionMaxSize = theMaxSize; 
        libraryCollection = new Material[collectionMaxSize]; 
    }

    public LibraryCollection(int theCollectSize, Material[] theArray)
    {
        collectionMaxSize = theCollectSize; 
        libraryCollection = theArray; 
    }


    //(1)----------------Find MATERIAL-----------------
    public Material findMaterial(String theFindMaterial)
    {
        if(theFindMaterial == null) 
        {
            return null; 
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < libraryCollection.length; i++)
        {
            if(libraryCollection[i] !=null && theFindMaterial.equals(libraryCollection[i].getMaterialId()))
            {
            return libraryCollection[i]; 
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Material ID & checkedOutPtron ID; 
    public boolean checkOutMaterial(String matrlID, String patronId)
    {
        Material thisMaterial = findMaterial(matrlID); 
        if(thisMaterial == null) 
        {
            System.out.println("The material doesn't exist" ); 
            return false; 
        }
        if(thisMaterial.checkedOut())
        {
            System.out.println("The material has been already checked out " ); 
            return false; 
        }
        thisMaterial.setCheckedOut(true);
        thisMaterial.setPatronCheckout(Integer.parseInt(patronId));//Convert string value into int

    return true; 
    }
```

//Material Class

```
public class Material 
{
    private static int materialID = 0 ; 
    private int mtrId; 
    private String title; 
    private boolean checkedOut ;
    private int checkedOutPatron; 


    public Material()
    {
        mtrId = 0; 
        title = ""; 
        checkedOut = false; 
        checkedOutPatron = 0; 
        }

    public Material(int theId, String theTitle)
    {
        mtrId = theId; 
        title = theTitle; 
    }

    //Getter Method 
    public String getMaterialId()
    {
        return mtrId + "";  
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title; 
    }

    public void setCheckedOut(boolean theCheckout)
    {
        checkedOut = theCheckout; 
    }

    public void setPatronCheckout(int patronCheckout)
    {
        checkedOutPatron = patronCheckout; 
    }


    public boolean checkedOut()
    {
        return checkedOut;
    }
    public int getCheckedOutPatron()
    {
        return checkedOutPatron; 
    }


    //ToString Method  
    public String toString()
        {
        return " \nMaterial ID: " + mtrId + " \nMaterial Title: " + title + " \nChecked Out: " 
        + checkedOut + " \nPatron check out: " + checkedOutPatron; 
        }

    public static int getNextID()
        {
        materialID++; 
        return materialID;
        }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the definition of the Material class?

Comment: You have not assigned the result of the findMaterial() call to anything.

Comment: HamishD, I shared my Material class.

Comment: FredK, I didn't get it. can you give me an example. thanks;

Comment: your are calling `findMaterial(null)` and in that case, `findMaterial()` returns `null`. So, what dou you expect to see on the console?

Comment: oh I see...got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run:

```
String search = null
librarycollectObj1.findMaterial(search);
```

You execute

```
public Material findMaterial(String theFindMaterial)
{
    if(theFindMaterial == null) 
    {
        return null; 
    }
```

Since `theFindMaterial = search` and `search = null` then you exit the method without doing anything because `theFindMaterial = null`.

You could do something like this:

```
public static LibraryCollection librarycollectObj1 = new LibraryCollection(10);

// Initialize the object somehow
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    librarycollectObj1.libraryCollection[i] = new Material(i, "");
}

String search = "1"; 
// Do some null checking in production code
System.out.println(librarycollectObj1.findMaterial(search). getMaterialId());
```

Comment: Thanks. It is my first java class. so perplexed. Hmm..can you give me an example of what kind of parameter with some logic. can I initialize it to search = "";  and also how do I call the checkOutMaterial() method?

Comment: I modified my answer. Check it out

Comment: got it. Thank you

Comment: Please, mark this answer as the solution for your question if that was the case

Comment: Yes, it is the solution for the findMaterial method. I still need help with the checkOutMaterial method though. I appreciate your help. btw, how to mark the answer as my solution?

Comment: There is a tick on the left side of the answer that you have to click. It shows. You could also vote up by clicking the triangle above the "0" number if you found the answer useful. I will vote up your question so everyone can see it was also helpful.